# What does .next(); do in this case?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

This is the code which expects the integer input. If the input is integer the loop ends else the input is asked again. But if I do not include sc.next(); it will go into infinite loop when non integer value is given. Here is the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean status = false;

        while (!status) {
            status = sc.hasNextInt();
            if (status){
                System.out.println("Number of people recorded");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter a valid integer number.");
            }
            sc.next();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `status` as a separate variable. You merely need to consume the token that isn't an `int` while you wait for an `int`. Like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Number of people recorded " + sc.nextInt());
        break; // <-- end the loop
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid integer number.");
        sc.next(); // <-- it's not an int, but consume whatever it is
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wish if you could help me on understanding how sc.next(); is preventing infinite loop.

Comment: @AnonymousSrest I tried once already. If the next token is **not** an `int`, then `sc.next();` will consume whatever the next token is (regardless of type). If you do not include that, then the next token (whatever it is) is **not** consumed. Let's say you input `x 1` - is the next token an `int` (it's `x`) so no. With `sc.next();` the `x` is removed. Without it, the next token is `x` ***forever***.

Answer (score 1):

`sc.hasNextInt()` tells you if the input is an integer or not. If it is, then the loop exits. If it isn't, then the loop continues. It continues infinitely because you never read what the input actually was, since `sc.hasNextInt()` is false. Including a `sc.next()` will actually get the input, pausing, and therefore not infinitely continuing the loop.